# hierarchical clustering of ternary matrix

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

I have a matrix with values `-1,0,1` of the form

```
array([[ 1,   1],
       [ 0,  -1],
       [ 1,  -1],
       [ 1,   1]
       [ -1,  1]])
```

and what I want is kind of a hierarchical clustering from left to right.

- The 'biggest' 3 clusters contain the data points, that have a -1,0 or 1 in the first dimension.
- The next 9 clusters are a refinement of the first 3 clusters such that they contain a

  - 1 at first dimension, 1 at second dimension or
  - 1 at first dimension, 0 at second dimension or
  - 1 at first dimension, -1 at second dimension or
  - 0 at first dimension, 1 at second dimension or
  - 0 at first dimension, 0 at second dimension or
  - 0 at first dimension, -1 at second dimension or
  - -1 at first dimension, 1 at second dimension or
  - -1 at first dimension, 0 at second dimension or
  - -1 at first dimension, -1 at second dimension

and so on.

The desired output should be

```
output = [[[0,3],[],[2]],[[1],[],[]],[[4],[],[]]]
```

because

data point 0 ([**1**,1]), data point 2 ([**1**,-1]) and data point 3 ([**1**,1]) are in the first big cluster, data point 1 ([**0**,-1]) is in the second big cluster, data point 4 ([**-1**,1]) is in the third big cluster and then the refinements concerning the second dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good example on clustering, I believe it's more of a classification case since the classes in this case are defined, and a deterministic code such as the proposition below is enough to classifiy all the entries:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 1,   1],
              [ 0,  -1],
              [ 1,  -1],
              [ 1,   1],
              [ -1,  1]])

def categorize(a):
    classes = [[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]],[[],[],[]]]
    def get_classes(x,y):
        idx = 0 if x==1 else 1 if x == 0  else 2
        idy = 0 if y==1 else 1 if y == 0  else 2
        return idx,idy

    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        idx,idy=get_classes(a[i,0],a[i,1])
        classes[idx][idy].append(i)
    return classes

output = categorize(a)
print(output)
```